# How to change a name of cloud directory?

Tags: functions, files-and-directories, wolfram-cloud

How to change a name of cloud directory? Such as `$CloudRootDirectory` will give an ugly, long and illegible directory name. How to change the name to be my custom? You can see,there are some meaningless and unreadable names in my `CloudDirectory`.

```
CloudEvaluate[
 g = NestGraph[Select[FileNames["*", #], DirectoryQ] &, Directory[], 
   2]; Graph[g, 
  VertexLabels -> 
   Table[a -> Placed[FileNameTake[a], Center], {a, VertexList[g]}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to set a custom name for your cloud objects?

Comment: @user6014 Can you?And for that cloud root directory?

Comment: I'm not sure... It seems to be very poorly documented. I just wanted to ensure I was understanding the question correctly. While I was looking into it.

Comment: @yode you can use `URLShorten`, is that what you need?

Comment: @Kuba The cloud fold have its name.I want to change it sometime.Like the local function `RenameDirectory`.

Comment: I'd ask WRI for serious answer but i.m.o. it can not be possible, what if I change `$CloudRootDirectory` to the same one that you want? It is a unique id that points to your cloud objects. Even `URLShorten` works automatically to avoid collisions.

Comment: @Kuba What you say make sense.Can you see that two red arrow?We can change the `fa5` or `4cf`,which isn't unique id anymore, into our custom name?

Comment: @Kuba, yode per [the pricing page](https://www.wolfram.com/development-platform/pricing/) you can set "Customizable URLs" if you pay, but it seems mad expensive for just that trivial benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rename your root directory or get rid of unreadable sequences in the url because there has to be something automatically distinctive for each user.

You can rename deeper directories though. `RenameDirectory` does not work but you can use `RenameFile` analogously to: [How to apply RenameFile to a CloudObject](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128079/5478)

```
co = CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"x" -> "Integer"}, #x! &], "dir/form"]
```

> ```
> CloudObject[https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-.../dir/form]
> ```

```
RenameFile[
 CloudObject["dir"],
 CloudObject["anotherDir"]
]
```

> ```
> CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-.../anotherDir"]
> ```

And confirmation that the original file is there:

```
CloudObjectInformation[#, "Path"] & /@ CloudObjects["anotherDir"]
```

> ```
> {"user-.../anotherDir/form"}
> ```

Comment: You have earned the bounties going to be expired. :)

Comment: @yode thanks, I'm glad it is helpful.

Comment: We achieve it eventually,but it's seem unreasonable.A folder in cloud is not a `CloudObject` I think.Such as you cannot find a folder by `CloudObjects`.How do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. But yes, directory doesn't seem to be a CloudObject but we can use this wrapper to not type full path and so that `RenameFIle` knows it should call the Cloud.