# How to apply RenameFile to a CloudObject

Tags: functions, files-and-directories, wolfram-cloud

As the [documemtation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RenameFile.html) in **Details and Options**:

> RenameFile works on cloud objects, changing their cloud file names but
>   not their UUIDs.

I think this sentense imply the `RenameFile` can apply into `CloudObject`,but the question is how to?There are some examples of failure:

```
g=CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"x"->"Integer"},#x!&]]
(* CloudObject[https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/a13f1c37-68e7-4d5b-a4d1-549ba0311230] *)

ToString[First[g]]
(* https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/a13f1c37-68e7-4d5b-a4d1-549ba0311230 *)

RenameFile[ToString[First[g]],"https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/testgname"]
(* $Failed *)

RenameFile[g,CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/testgname"]]
(* $Failed *)
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen if each of us change one of our urls to `https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/testgname`?

Comment: @Kuba Yes,can we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify the url fully, it has to contain information that it is yours. So `$WolframUUID` needs to be there, you can change the name:

```
co = CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"x" -> "Integer"}, #x! &], "name"]
```

> ```
> CloudObject[https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-..../name]
> ```

```
RenameFile[co, CloudObject["anotherName"]]
```

> ```
> CloudObject[https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-..../anotherName]
> ```

Alternatively you can use `URLShorten` to make it more compact.

Comment: Wow,it is exactly what I want.Thanks a lot.And I note the anonymous `CloudObject` is not in my cloud directory and we cannot find it in [this page](https://develop.wolframcloud.com/app/)?